# how to clear the gap of UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, arabic

As we know, UITextField will keep a gap in right edge when length of text is larger than length of textfield. may be 10 pixel or somewhat. 
[LTR, right gap, may be 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLu6.png)

However,when the input mode is Arabic(is right-to-left), the gap appears in the left edge,and it's larger than 10. somebody know why?
[RTL, left gap, larger than 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvjyh.png)

I want to custom the gap, no matter the input mode is english or arabic. First, I should clear the gap, and then override editingRectForBounds: or textRectForBounds:, so how can i clear the gap?

Comment: Please can you add a screenshot of which gap you are referring to and how you want it to behave in RTL and LTR languages. Would help clear up what you are asking. Thanks :D

Comment: One guess could be arabic is written in other way around I think. Can you share a screen ??

Comment: ok, i added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `leftView` and `rightView` of textField. Something like,

```
   UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)];
standardTextField.leftView = paddingView;
standardTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
standardTextField.rightView = paddingView;
standardTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

40 is the height of `standardTextField`. This will set padding of size (10,40) on both side of textfield.

Comment: that seems doesn't works, because the original right gap still exists, this will make the right gap be 10 + 10 = 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a `UIView` and add `textField` into that view. Set `textField` border is none.

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

And adjust `texField` size according to your requirement. For example,

1. If you want `textField` of width 100, then
2. Create `UIView` of width 100
3. Put `textField` and set it origin x far, say 5 pixels. and also adjust width.

Comment: When you switch to input mode, it will never change frame. So it will work.

Comment: so, as you mean, how to adjust width ?

Comment: adjust width according to your requirement in `nib(.xib or storyboard)` or if you add programmatically, then adjust at a time of creating its object.